# Style binding depending on condition in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have some code like that:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + order.image_url_medium + ') top right no-repeat #118cc8'}">Content</div>
```

But how can I bind it depending on condition? So if `order.image_url_medium` exists, put it to style `<div [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + order.image_url_medium + ') top right no-repeat #118cc8'}">Content</div>`, else - just - leave blank div `<div>Content</div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view:

```
<div [ngStyle]="divStyle">Content</div>
```

In your component:

```
this.divStyle = {};
if (someCondition) {
    this.divStyle.background = `url(${this.order.image_url_medium}) top right no-repeat #118cc8`;
}
```